# Remove parts of a string based on pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following Pattern:

```js
ptrn = "url/{test1}/url2/{test2}/url3?param1=&param2="
```

and following string

```js
fullURL = "url/abcd/url2/efgh/url3?param1=&param2="
```

I want to remove `{test1}` and `{test2}` from the `fullURL`-string, so that the outcome looks like this:

```js
modifiedfullURL = "url//url2//url3?param1=&param2="
```

`"abcd"` and `"efgh"` can be everything else dependent on the call.
Is there any way to do this "clean"?

I tried with regex, but here of course the pattern can always change, so it would be nice if i can identify the strings which needs to be replaced, based on the pattern.

Comment: *"I tried with regex, but here of course the pattern can always change"* What does that mean? You've shown a specific pattern, in which the second and fourth segments are the ones you want to remove. What changes? Please update your question with details ([more here](/help/how-to-ask)) as well as the range of inputs you need to handle and the outputs you expect, and **your** attempt to solve the problem, so we can help you with it.

Comment: Why do you need `fullURL` at all? The result you're looking for could be achieved by removing `{placeholder}`s from `ptrn` instead. `const modifiedfullURL = ptrn.replace(/{[^{}/]*}/g, "")`. See [this diagram](https://regexper.com/#%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%2F%5D*%7D) for the regex explanation.

Comment: "Clean" in this context IMHO can only mean, that you use a package made for this kind of stuff to begin with, instead of trying to "hack" it yourself. https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to remove the items in odd positions. ie, 1st index, 3rd index etc.

If that the case, then it could be done easily using the below methods.

```js
const test1 = 'abcd';
const test2 = 'efgh'
const fullUrl = `url/${test1}/url2/${test2}/url3?param1=&param2=`

const modifiedUrl = fullUrl.split('/').filter((_, index)=> index % 2 === 0).join('//');
console.log("fullUrl", "=>", fullUrl);
console.log("modifiedUrl", "=>", modifiedUrl);
```

const modifiedUrl = fullUrl.split('/').filter((segment, index)=> index % 2 === 0).join('//');
console.log(modifiedUrl);

Comment: It looks like there is unformatted code below the current code snippet...is it meant to be part of that or a separate block of code?

Comment: It's just the same in the above snippet. So, it's readable but kept it in the body for easy copies.